# Intent to Play store?

Tags: android

I want the button called "More Apps" to access my list of apps on the play store .
 This is the page link :

https://play.google.com/store/apps/developer?id=Jouni

??

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Do this in your button OnClick

```
String url = "https://play.google.com/store/apps/developer?id=Jouni";
Intent i = new Intent(Intent.ACTION_VIEW);
i.setData(Uri.parse(url));
startActivity(i);
```

Comment: great, but can I make it open play store automatically, not view selection window (Browser,PlayStore,FireFox)

Comment: Try something like this? Intent intent = new Intent( Intent.ACTION_VIEW );
    intent.setData( Uri.parse( "market://details?id=<YOUR_APP_PACKAGE>" ) );
    startActivity( intent );

Answer (score 6):

Launch Google Play Store works fine with some Market URI:

```
        Intent intent = new Intent(Intent.ACTION_VIEW);
        intent.setData(Uri.parse(<market_uri>));
        intent.setFlags(Intent.FLAG_ACTIVITY_NEW_TASK | Intent.FLAG_ACTIVITY_CLEAR_TOP | Intent.FLAG_ACTIVITY_NO_ANIMATION);

        startActivity(intent);
```

where uris can be

- market://details?id=
- market://search?q=pub:

But it's **not working when you want to launch it on the welcome page** , i.e., when you just want to Launch Google Play Store whitout specifying an app id or perform a query.

So I came up with this solution which also handles the case where 'market://' uris can't be processed by any app. In this case, use Web browser as a fall-back.

This solution is not the best, but it does the job.

```
public void launchPlayStore()
{
    // look for intent able to process 'market://' uris
    Intent market = new Intent(Intent.ACTION_VIEW, Uri.parse("market://search?q=dummy"));

    PackageManager packageManager = getPackageManager();

    ComponentName playStoreComponentName=null;

    for(ResolveInfo resolveInfo : packageManager.queryIntentActivities(market, 0))
    {
        ActivityInfo activityInfo = resolveInfo.activityInfo;

        String packageName = activityInfo.applicationInfo.packageName;

        // lokking for "com.android.vending", "com.google.android.finsky.activities.MainActivity"
        if (!packageName.contains("android"))// || !activityInfo.name.contains("android"))
            continue;

        // appname should be 'Play Store'
        // String appName = resolveInfo.loadLabel(packageManager).toString();
        playStoreComponentName =  new ComponentName(packageName, activityInfo.name);
        break;
    }

    if(playStoreComponentName!=null)
    {
        Intent intent = new Intent();
        intent.setComponent(playStoreComponentName);
        intent.setData(Uri.parse("market://"));
        intent.setFlags(Intent.FLAG_ACTIVITY_NEW_TASK | Intent.FLAG_ACTIVITY_CLEAR_TOP | Intent.FLAG_ACTIVITY_NO_ANIMATION);

        // launch Google Play Store app :-)
        startActivity(intent);
    }
    else
    {
        Intent intent = new Intent(Intent.ACTION_VIEW);
        intent.setData(Uri.parse("https://play.google.com/"));
        intent.setFlags(Intent.FLAG_ACTIVITY_NEW_TASK | Intent.FLAG_ACTIVITY_CLEAR_TOP | Intent.FLAG_ACTIVITY_NO_ANIMATION);

        // fallback -> web browser
        startActivity(intent);
    }
}
```